# Laravel php artisan "Class request does not exist"

Tags: php, laravel, request, laravel-artisan

I'm working with Laravel,

suddenly when I try to run `php artisan serve` in my command prompt,

it's displaying the error message:

```
In Container.php line 729: Class request does not exist
```

I have looked in all my controllers, models, and other files I could think of for loose Request references, but found nothing.

How do I debug this?

Comment: post complete error log.

Comment: I think some classes do not exist so remove `composer.lock` and `vendor` directory, then run `composer install` and test again.

Comment: check your controller.php there may be `Request` reference in your action like this `public function index(Request $request)`, for this you need to import `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

Answer (score 5):

I was having this problem because a config file was calling the `request` helper function.

Since I did not use this configuration when running my application from console, I just checked if the request was running from console before using the `request` helper. For example,

```php
# my config file

return [
    'conf_key' => (app()->runningInConsole() === false) ? request()?->headers?->get('origin') : null,
// ...
```

Answer (score 4):

I was using `request()` in `config.php`, and I don't know why this works until some day that crash with this error. The site was working well, but composer/artisan commands fail. I think it's normal, because there is no request... I handled checking `isset($_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"])`, because I need the `SERVER_NAME` to config some parameters.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read how to [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I've created a cache directory in bootstrap directory and my problem solved

Comment: Answers should include the exact code needed to solve the OP's problem.This is welcome info, but more appropriately left as a Comment.

Comment: This solved my problem, and I have no idea why this would happen.

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this issue for a while.

Turns out, my issue was in a config file. One of my config classes was calling a static method with a bug in it.

The way I found it was to add echo statements in the following 2 files:

`vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container.php`

To echo the classes the container is building.

```
/**
 * Instantiate a concrete instance of the given type.
 *
 * @param  string  $concrete
 * @return mixed
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
 */
public function build($concrete)
{
    // If the concrete type is actually a Closure, we will just execute it and
    // hand back the results of the functions, which allows functions to be
    // used as resolvers for more fine-tuned resolution of these objects.
    if ($concrete instanceof Closure) {
        return $concrete($this, $this->getLastParameterOverride());
    }

    echo 'Build - ' . $concrete . PHP_EOL;
    $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
```

and here.

`vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguratio n.php`

To echo the config classes being loaded.

```
/**
 * Load the configuration items from all of the files.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application  $app
 * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Config\Repository  $repository
 * @return void
 * @throws \Exception
 */
protected function loadConfigurationFiles(Application $app, RepositoryContract $repository)
{
    $files = $this->getConfigurationFiles($app);

    if (! isset($files['app'])) {
        throw new Exception('Unable to load the "app" configuration file.');
    }

    foreach ($files as $key => $path) {
        echo 'config - ' .$key . PHP_EOL;
        $repository->set($key, require $path);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recheck your Controller class exists, because this error is thrown when there is some difference in Controller class name like

```
class PostController extends Controller { }
```

and

```
class Postcontroller extends Controller { }
```

Notice small "C"

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a problem with permission to `bootstrap/cache` on CI server. Check this directory twice.